# En contexto culinario, ¿cómo se puede decir 'wrap' en español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, comida

Estoy buscando un término que describa bien la palabra inglesa "wrap" (como en un wrap de chocolate), pero que no sea *wrap*.

Se me ocurre **rollito**, **rollo** o hasta **envuelto** (pero este último tiene ya una connotación bien clara y diferente a la de *wrap*, o por lo menos es así en Colombia). Investigando, vi que se aconseja también **rol**, pero esta nunca la he visto y me parece muy innatural.

¿Qué posibilidades se les ocurren?

Comment: Tiene sus propias connotaciones (con respecto al relleno), pero hay *burrito*, que significa el mismo concepto básico de un 'wrap' (en mi dialecto de inglés, *wrap* significa algo salado, jamás he oído "a chocolate wrap").

Comment: Me imagino que eres mi compatriota y pienso que desde el punto de vista comercial lo puedes seguir llamando _wrap_ ya que la mayoría lo entendemos (al menos Medellín y Bogotá) Si definitivamente lo quieres decir en español yo recomendaría los nombres mexicanos tacos, burritos o fajitas.

Comment: yo le diria burrito, aunque no por la traduccion si no que en mexico a cualquier cosa rellena por una tortilla de harina se le dice burrito, 
aunque por otro lado, un burrito y un wrap si son cosas distintas, principalmente por que el burrito se prepara calentando una tortilla, pero el wrap es con la tortilla fria

Comment: Huuuuuy este tema da para mucho en México, donde si osas llamar "burrito" a esas abominaciones culinarias (tacos de ensalada les digo yo). Existe todavía la controversia Norte vs Centro del país, sobre si las quesadillas llevan queso (en el norte decimos que si, en el sur dicen que todo está en la tortilla: enrollada es taco, doblada es quesadilla) el burrito es un taco, excepto que el taco lleva tortilla de maiz, y el burrito es de tortilla de harina, sin importar los ingredientes en ambos casos. Pero nunca sin carne, Sea pollo, res, cerdo, o cazón o cualquier cosa que camine o se deslice

Comment: ¿Tu propósito es encontrar un término que funcione entre familia, que no se confunda con otros platos que ya tienen su carácter bien definido, como por ejemplo *burrito*?  ¿O estás acaso tratando de describir a un amigo un plato que probaste en EEUU?  Danos el contexto, pues, por favor.

Answer (score 3):

Aunque "rollo" es una manera coloquial de referirse a ellos, en España en algunos establecimientos de comida se los llama **flautas** ([imágenes](https://www.google.es/search?tbm=isch&q=flautas%20de%20pollo%20y%20queso)). El DLE recoge esta acepción, aunque la pone como regional:

> [**flauta**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I3rm1yY)
>
> 3. f. Méx. Taco más largo de lo común, hecho de una tortilla de maíz enrollada, rellena de carne y frita.

También por analogía con otros platos mexicanos se usa a veces **fajitas** ([imágenes](https://www.google.es/search?tbm=isch&q=fajitas%20de%20jamon)) o **burritos** ([imágenes](https://www.google.es/search?tbm=isch&q=burritos%20de%20espinacas)), especialmente si el *wrap* se hace con una tortilla como las de allá.

Si nos vamos a lo dulce, creo que aquí lo más habitual es hablar de *crêpe* o **crep** ([imágenes](https://www.google.es/search?tbm=isch&q=crep%20de%20chocolate)):

> **[crep](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BEdJfiv)**
>
> 2. m. o f. Tortita muy fina de harina, leche y huevos, que suele servirse enrollada y con un relleno dulce o salado. U. m. en pl.

No obstante, también existe el concepto de "**crep salado**" ([imágenes](https://www.google.es/search?tbm=isch&q=crep%20salado)) que al fin y al cabo es lo mismo que un *wrap* solo que la masa es diferente.

Comment: De acuerdo, yo me iría con los nombres mexicanos. Tacos, burritos y fajitas.